# How to do row-level security allowing multiple accessId to match the row's id in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, predicate, sql-function, row-level-security

I use a function as BLOCK and FILTER PREDICATE in order to implement row-level security.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AccessPredicate] 
    (@accessId int)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN 
        SELECT 1 AS AccessPredicateResult
        WHERE @accessId = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'accessId ') AS int)
```

I now need to modify the session context variable to hold any number of accessId. Since it is a `SQL_VARIANT` type, I cannot use a `TABLE` variable or custom one. I resorted to a CSV list as `NVARCHAR`, e.g. `1,2,3`

That means I need to update the `SELECT` query in my function to do a 'WHERE @accessId IN (...)'. Of course I can't just

```
SELECT 1 AS AccessPredicateResult
WHERE @accessId IN (CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'accessId ') AS VARCHAR)) -- where accessId = '1,2,3'
```

Without liking the implications, I tried to do that by putting the whole query into a `@sql VARCHAR` variable and then `EXEC sp_executesql @sql` but that failed because SQL Server cannot have a `DECLARE` in a table valued function (for whatever reason!?). Neither does the table valued function allow `EXEC` a stored procedure as far as my research suggests.

I'm blocked by this, can't think of a way to do this now.

So I've got the allowed `accessId` in my C# code and somehow need to persist them in the session context (or are there other, well performing, methods?) so that my predicate can use it to confirm the row in question is accessible. What's the best way forward now?

Thanks

Comment: _SQL Server cannot have a DECLARE in a table valued function (for whatever reason!?)_ Sure you can. You can't have one in an Inline Table-Valued Function, however, because that's essentially a single statement like a `view`. Have you tried using CTEs to define what you might have used as scalar variables via `declare`?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? Since you're probably already on SQL Server 2016 to be using row-level security why not use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) on the session context?

Comment: 2016 is the miniumum I need to support, yes.

Comment: SPLIT_STRING is king. Thanks for pointing me into that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` in a subquery

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.AccessPredicate
    (@accessId int)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
SELECT 1 AS AccessPredicateResult
WHERE @accessId IN (
    SELECT s.value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'accessId') AS varchar(4000)), ',')
);
```

I warn you though, that RLS is not foolproof security, and can be circumvented by a user able to craft custom queries.

---

**As a side note:** Why does SQL Server not allow variables or `EXEC` in functions?

`EXEC` is not allowed because a function must not be side-affecting.

Furthermore, an *inline* table function must be a single statement, therefore it makes no sense to `DECLARE` variables. It is effectively a parameterized view, and functions that way as far as the compiler is concerned.

If you do need to "declare" variables, you can use a `VALUES` virual table, along with `CROSS APPLY`. For example:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.AccessPredicate
    (@accessId int)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
SELECT c2.Calc2 AS AccessPredicateResult
FROM (VALUES(
    SomeCalculationHere
)) AS c1(Calc1)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    SomeFunction(c1.Calc1)
)) AS c2(Calc2);
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote more. Thanks for the added explanation around EXEC and DECLARE (_inline_ table function)! Kudos for pointing out RLS not being bullet proof. SQL injection can surely affect this. It's just one part of the security net for me.